# hide comment in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

When the "comment" function is disabled in the blog, would it be more sensible to indicate "0 comment" it can delete this mention? How the code will look like?

https://prnt.sc/k2jdoz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What theme are you applying on your site?

Normally, you can go through the source code (the template) to delete that tag, it takes a bit time to figure out exactly line code showing that element.

Another way (not recommend but easier for you if you don't expert in WordPress or PHP): use the inspect element and set CSS for that element to not display (collapse, invisible..)